# Smart way to compute decomposition of a prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x) = X^5 -4x +2$. I am wondering if there is a way to compute the decomposition of $(5)$ in $K = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$ without computing the decomposition of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

What I'm thinking is that there should be a local field argument (maybe using newton polygons ?) but I don't know it.

I would be interested in the most general answer possible.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to though. I'd be thanking god that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ was monogeneic (in fact it is just $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where $f(\alpha)=0$) and using the Dedekind-Kummer theorem--factoring $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ is really not that hard. Is there any reason why you'd not want to use the Dedekind-Kummer Theorem?

Comment: Yes of course it's easy to compute decomposition in $\mathbb{F}_5$ but the thing is that I feel there should be a less painful way to do it and one that generalizes to cases where it's not as easy to do by hand. (I just happened to have this example nearby)

Comment: I mean, like what type of things were you thinking? The fact that the number of primes above $p$ is the number of primes in $K\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_5$? I haven't checked, is your example Galois?

Comment: Something along the lines as $f$ has such and such roots in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ with such and such multiplicities so the decomposition is this. (sorry if I'm not very clear but english isn't my mother tong).

Comment: Did you see my last comment?

Comment: well yes I was thinking of something that would use the fact that $K \otimes \mathbb{Q}_5 \cong \prod_{\mathfrak{p}|5} K_p$. It is very possible though that my question doesn't have a positive answer. I haven't checked if it is Galois, why is it important ? (hope this last question didn't sound too stupid :-) )

Comment: But, I guess what I don't understand, is that decomposing $K\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}_5$ this amounts, in some sense to factoring $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ by Hensel's lemma.

Comment: Ok so I guess my question dosent have positive answer. Tanks a lot anyway :-)

Comment: So, should we pursue this further, or should I post an answer? :)

Comment: You are welcome to post an answer.